Line 4: Range setFormulaLocal: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format. Can anyone help me with office script error
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
// Set range B3 on selectedSheetyour text fetching info from new sheet in same xcel 
selectedSheet.getRange("B3").setFormulaLocal("=IF(SAPAnalyticsReportÜbersichtKP!A2<>"",SAPAnalyticsReportÜbersichtKP!B2)"); i get error at this place
}
im trying to work in excel with office scripts to fetch a value from another sheet in same workbook. If cell1 is not empty then i need cell3 value from the sheet

Use double quotes within your formula string --> A2<>"""". And probably the German version of the formula as you are using setFormulaLocal.
